# Calculating correlation coefficient when x has contributed to y

Tags: correlation

I have a very brief background in statistics, and want to know if there is a "simple" way to approach finding a correlation coefficient when the data set is comprised of results where $x$ value is a known weighted proportion of the $y$ value.

I am a computer programmer and I am looking for a computationally efficient answer. I may already have an answer that I think is "good enough" below, but don't know enough stats to know!

**Some context:**

A class of students write an assessment which is graded and counts 30% of their final result. I want to see how this result correlates with their "other" results. The simplest way to do this is to find the correlation between that assessment and their final result.

This hasn't been seen to be a large problem since most classes have several assessments of reasonably low, equal weighting and so identifying an assessment with "poor" correlation is still possible.

One large shortcoming, however, is that the assessment will tend to correlate perfectly ($r=1$) as the proportion of the assessments weighting in the final result tends to 1.

The goal here, is to identify assessments that have results in a different rank order to one that might be expected. Once these have been identified, the idea is to examine what about that assessment caused the upset.

**Possible solution:**

My immediate thought is that one could use the final result and, reasonably easily, calculate a new final result, excluding the effect of the $x$ variable, given known proportion $p$:

$${{y}_{new}}_i = \frac{{y_i}-x_i.p}{1-p}$$

**Example:**

An assessment counts 30% of the final result. Student $i$ achieves 80% ($x_i$) for the assessment and a final grade of 75% ($y_i$):

$${{y}_{new}}_i = \frac{75-80.0.3}{1-0.3}=\frac{51}{0.7}=72.857...$$

One could then calculate a new set of $y_{new}$ values and proceed with calculating the correlation coefficient.

**Question:**

My question is whether there is a suitable statistical calculation that already takes this weighted scenario into account?

Is comparing an assessment to the final result, in this way, valid?

Finally, are there better approaches to this problem?

Comment: I don't see that the correlation has to tend to 1. If you were correlating the *total* score w/ the other assignments, yes, but not if you are correlating the new score with the other assignments. Do you want to include the weighting of the different assignments (thus assuming it is correct), or check if the weighting is reasonable, or ignore it? (Those are all different questions.)

Comment: Hi @gung - the data that we have to use is the assessment score and the final result, which includes that assessment. As I have said, it is possible to calculate the "final result without the assessment" using some elementary ratios. We simply want to check the assessment's correlation to the "others" - and are using the final result as an approximate version of that. Since it is included in the final result, as the proportion of the assessment is higher, it has a larger influence on the final result and thus the correlation improves by virtue of that alone.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if you can subtract the score for the assignment in question. I suspect the final total is bounded (eg, can't be >100). Do students tend to be close to the bound? Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @gung - all scores are bounded 0 to 100. Here is an example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UK8TxLeIYq6BOVrA8ZmwQBUMqoqJzcRzASMNgwd2RpY/edit?usp=sharing . This is output from code (note that because of rounding, the final results are a touch off - these are taken care of in code). Here, the correlation uses the assessment in the final result.